# Count *.pdf files in a folder and update adjacent column in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

[image]

I have the following excel spreadsheet, tracker.xls with 2 columns: category and count.

I want to loop through a subdirectory which contains pdf files which match the category column in my spreadsheet.

[image]

This is what I've done so far, but my code does not seem to be working:

```
Sub CV()

    Function CVCount()

        CategoryArray = Range("A2:A3")
        CountArray = Range("B2:B3")

        For i = 1 To UBound(CategoryArray)

            For j = 1 To UBound(CategoryArray, 2)

            'get name of category

            Dim Category As String
            Category = (myarray(i, j))
            FolderPath = Category + "\"
            path = FolderPath & "\*.pdf"
            Filename = Dir(path)

                For k = 1 To UBound(CountArray)

                    For l = 1 To UBound(CountArray, 2)

                        'get count

                        Do While Filename <> ""
                            count = count + 1
                            Filename = Dir()
                        Loop

                        'assign count to cell
                        Range("").Value = count

                Next k

            Next j

        Next i

    End Function

End Sub
```

I can't seem to figure out how to assign a count to a cell. Any ideas how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but it's far simpler than that:

```
    Option Explicit

Private Const baseFolder As String = "C:\Users\Hazel\Documents\Personal\Accounts\Childcare\"

 Sub countFiles()

    Dim path As String
    Dim fileName As Variant
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1

    Do While Range("A" & i + 1).Value <> ""

        count = 0

        i = i + 1
        path = baseFolder & Range("A" & i).Value & "\"

        fileName = Dir(path)

        Do While fileName <> ""

            If UCase$(Right(fileName, 3)) = "PDF" Then count = count + 1
            fileName = Dir()

        Loop

        Range("B" & i).Value = count

    Loop

End Sub
```

Just change the "baseFolder" constant to match your starting directory.

Comment: Thanks. What if the starting directory is where the xlsm file is kept. Can it not be identified automatically?

Comment: Yes use `ActiveWorkbook.Path`.